# How can two java apps communicate on two instances on EC2?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipc

I plan on having two java Apps, each running on a separate instance on AWS Ec2, assume Parser application on instance1, and Indexer application on instance 2. When Parser is finished parsing docs, I want to send a bundle of docs to indexer instance so it can do its indexing. How can I achieve the notification from app1 to app2? My initial thought is sockets. Are there better ideas of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct process communication is one way. It may be harder to manage and scale this though.

You could also use SQS or another message queue to to queue work for the other instance(s). Generally with that option, you would want to store your payload in a shared location (like S3) as messages often have a size limit.

Using a message queue allows you to add additional workers, presuming your application allows for it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the AWS Simple Workflow (SWF) service.  This requires you to structure your application into the SWF framework and it has a bit of a learning curve, but it would take care of dispatching your tasks across the multiple instances and ensuring that each step is executed with error handling and event log.

I'd recommend first reading the faq http://aws.amazon.com/swf/faqs/ and then working through the developer guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/welcome.html

It currently supports java, ruby, .net, and php.